# post on Google plus stream with custom Content

Tags: google-plus

I want to know that, is there any way to post our Formatted(Bold and Italic or \n) text as content of Post on User stream (using google plus Api).

I have tried Intractive Posts and share dialog offered by google but they do not support formatted content.

Comment: Please include more details. How are you trying to format the content. What happens to that formatting, etc.

Comment: I have tried <br> &nbsp <b> and other HTML tags but google show all tags as a content in dialog box. you can see #class demo link.

Comment: Google+ doesn't support HTML formatting in posts. Have you tried using the formatting G+ does support? `_italic_ *bold* -striketrhough-`

Comment: not working. you can check this demo [http://wheresgus.com/ipostdemo/]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As best I know, you cannot control whether the content that Google calculates from your page content will be bold or not.  However, in post content, you can * BOLD * and _ ITALICIZE _ using tags similar to markdown. Because you can pre-fill text in interactive posts, you can just pre-fill some **bold** words for your users suggesting they emphasize content in shares from your site.

Some code:

This goes in your page head tags

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
   var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
   po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';
   var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
 })();
</script>
```

... and this goes in the body

```
<!-- Place the tag where you want the button to render -->
<span
  class="g-interactivepost"
  data-contenturl="http://wheresgus.com/ipostdemo/gplusbw.png"
  data-contentdeeplinkid="/nothingtoseehere"
  data-clientid="268858962829.apps.googleusercontent.com"
  data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
  data-prefilltext="Prefill *bold* and _italic_ content."
  data-calltoactionlabel="JOIN"
  data-calltoactionurl="https://plus.google.com/+GusClass"
  data-calltoactiondeeplinkid="/account/signup">
<img src="gplusbw.png" width=28 height=23>
</span>
```

[Demo here](http://wheresgus.com/ipostdemo).

Comment: Your example have the same issue. Google plus API does not recognize HTML or any tag, instead of this it treat them as a content.

Comment: It does treat them as content but when the user shares the content, ** content ** will appear as bold.